# How does the context class works in asp.net mvc? How it loads all the data from database to further use?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I just want to know how the Context class works. Does it loads all the data at compile time or loads necessary data in run time. Because i have always created the context class object to access the data or to store data to database. Here is a simple code given to make the question clear:

```
StudentContext db = new StudentContext();

public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.student = db.students.ToList();

    return View();
}
```

OR

```
var check = db.users.Where(w=>w.UserName.ToLower()==user.UserName.ToLower());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DbContext` class is part of [MS Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx). This is an object-relational mapper that creates SQL statements from your LINQ expressions and uses them to access the database at runtime. See also [LINQ to Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb386964%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

> I am new in ASP.NET MVC. I just want to know how the Context class works.

ASP.NET MVC has no Context class. What you mean is the context class of the Entity Framework. ASP.NET has nothing specific there - much like you never ask "how does a mobile phone work in a mercedes car" because the way your mobile phone workds DOES NOT DEPEND ON YOUR CAR.

> Does it loads all the data at compile time

How utterly stupid would it be to load the data at COMPILE time? What if the data changes while the application is running? Most databases exist for data to be EDITED.

> or loads necessary data in run time.

Which makes a lot more sense, or? Because imagine - people, especially multiple  users, may change the data. Preloading it is problematic - particularly if you do it at ocmpile time. With non trivial applications - which are distributed compiled even for web pages (precompilation is a feature you have) - that would mean

- The program may load hundreds of gigabytes of data at compile time
- Which may be months old.

Ups. Makes absolutely no sense. Which is why things do not work like this.

- Every context has it's own cache of loaded data
- Do not keep them around (static dbcontext is a bad idea, generally. It makes sense in VERY rare circumstances).
- They load data as needed. This is particularly the case if / when you do queries, but also lazy loading when you follow navigation properties.

And again, this has nothing to do with MVC - this is Entity Framework we talk about, and you can easily use it outside of a web application.